# cordova.file is undefined in ionic project for android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an `ionic app` for `android`. I need to read a file from the sdcard for which I'm using `ngcordova plugin`. 
I have required `ngCordova` in the angular module in `app.js`
I am injecting the `ngcordova` before the `cordova.js` in my `index.html`. 
Installed it using

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file

I have injected `$cordovaFile` in my controller.

Whenever I try to read a file using the below code, I get the error, `cannot read property externalDataDirectory of undefined`

```
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            console.log('cordova.file.externalDataDirectory: ' + cordova.file.externalDataDirectory);
            myFsRootDirectory1 = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/'; // path for tablet
            myFsRootDirectory2 = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/'; // path for phone
            fileTransferDir = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
            if (fileTransferDir.indexOf(myFsRootDirectory1) === 0) {
                fileDir = fileTransferDir.replace(myFsRootDirectory1, '');
            }
            if (fileTransferDir.indexOf(myFsRootDirectory2) === 0) {
                fileDir = fileTransferDir.replace(myFsRootDirectory2, '');
            }
            console.log('Android FILETRANSFERDIR: ' + fileTransferDir);
            console.log('Android FILEDIR: ' + fileDir);

            $cordovaFile.readAsText(fileDir + 'a.csv').then(function(result) {
                    console.log('readAsText: ', result);
                    alert(result)
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    alert(err)
                });
        })
```

I have tried to print the cordova as well, but it does not contain the file object

```
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        alert(angular.toJson(window.cordova))
    })
```

I have also done `build cordova android`
removed and added the `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file`
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

Here are the versions:

```
"ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.3.1",
"ngCordova": "^0.1.27-alpha"
```

I'm testing this on the device and building a new apk each time for testing, not in `webview`.

Please help me resolve this issue or if you could recommend me a different method to get around this issue, that would be great!

Thanks for the answers

Comment: have check ngCordova file is loading? if not then go to chrome://inspect and check resouces for ngcordova file

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala: Thanks for the response, I can see ngcodova.js is being loaded in chrome. Is there anything else you can recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated the config.xml file with any extra plugin configuration, maybe this solves the problem you are facing. Check the plugin documentation for more information.

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />             
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
```

More information [Plugin website](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#configuring-the-plugin-optional)

**Update - try following**

```
npm update -g
cordova -v
cordova platform list
cordova platform update ios (or whatever platforms)
cordova platform list
cordova plugin list
-- now either do a cordova plugin remove/add for each plugin to update
-- OR with ionic use ionic state reset and it will install all from package.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have added this but it still doesn't solve the issue. I get the same alert for cordvoa, same contents. Is there anything else you could recommend?

Comment: I've updated my answer above - since it's prettier to show. If possible, maybe you can make your code public through a download link?

Comment: Thanks a ton @daan.desmedt
This helped the solve the issue. 
I build the app on a different machine than the one i develop and i use git to sync them.
Plugins are in .gitignore hence I was not able to access them. 
`ionic state reset ` helped me fix this issue.